# K3s traefik ingress returns gateway timeout

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, traefik-ingress, k3s

I am currently playing around with a rpi based k3s cluster and I am observing a weird phenomenon.

I deployed two applications.
The first one is nginx which I can reach on the url http://external-ip/foo based on the following ingress rule:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: foo
  namespace: foo
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/rule-type: "PathPrefixStrip"
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: "/"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /foo
        backend:
          serviceName: foo-service
          servicePort: 8081
```

And the other one is grafana which I cannot reach on the url http://external-ip/grafana based on the below ingress rule:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: grafana
  namespace: grafana
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/rule-type: "PathPrefixStrip"
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: "/"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /grafana
        backend: 
          serviceName: grafana-service
          servicePort: 3000
```

When I do a port-forward directly on the pod I can reach the grafana app, when I use the port-forward on the grafana service it also works.

However as soon as I try to reach it through the subpath I will get a gateway timeout.

Does anyone have a guess what I am missing?

Here the deployment and service for the grafana deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: grafana
  namespace: grafana
  labels:
    app: grafana
    tier: frontend
    service: monitoring
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: grafana
      tier: frontend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: grafana
        tier: frontend
        service: monitoring
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: grafana
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: grafana
        envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: grafana-config
        ports:
        - name: frontend
          containerPort: 3000
          protocol: TCP
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: grafana-service
  namespace: grafana
  labels:
    app: grafana
    tier: frontend
    service: monitoring
spec:
  selector:
    app: grafana
    tier: frontend
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: frontend
    port: 3000
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 3000
```

## Solution

I had to add the following two parameters to my configmap to make it work:

```
GF_SERVER_ROOT_URL=http://localhost:3000/grafana/   
GF_SERVER_FROM_SUB_PATH=true
```

Comment: Your nginx probably listen on `/` and you rewrite every path on it, so it works. The question is if grafana listen on `/`? What is your grafana.ini configuration root url? Take a look at this [comment](https://github.com/helm/charts/issues/6264#issuecomment-480530680) on github.

Comment: @jt97 thx this lead me to the right track, I had to set sub_path to true. I will edit my question. another useful link was the following https://grafana.com/tutorials/run-grafana-behind-a-proxy/#1 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments grafana is not listening on `/` like default nginx.

There is related [github issue](https://github.com/helm/charts/issues/6264) about this, and if you want to make it work you should specify root_url

```
grafana.ini:
  server:
    root_url: https://subdomain.example.com/grafana
```

Specifically take a look at [this](https://github.com/helm/charts/issues/6264#issuecomment-480530680) and [this](https://github.com/helm/charts/issues/6264#issuecomment-463755283) comment.

---

@tehemaroo add his own solution which include changing root url and sub_path in configmap

> I had to add the following two parameters to my configmap to make it work:

```
GF_SERVER_ROOT_URL=http://localhost:3000/grafana/   
GF_SERVER_FROM_SUB_PATH=true
```

And related [documentation](https://grafana.com/tutorials/run-grafana-behind-a-proxy/#1) about that

> To serve Grafana behind a sub path:
>
> Include the sub path at the end of the root_url.
>
> Set serve_from_sub_path to true.

```
[server]
domain = example.com
root_url = %(protocol)s://%(domain)s:%(http_port)s/grafana/
serve_from_sub_path = true
```